# How to cast object in object into Angular Class (Type)

Tags: angular, typescript

How can I cast `obj.category` into `Category` type in example below?

I need this to set selected options in dropdown.

```
export class Category{
    id: number;
    name: string;

    constructor(obj: any) {
        this.id = obj.id;
        this.name = obj.name;
    }
}


export class Post {
    category: Category[];

    constructor(obj: any) {
        this.category = obj.category;
    }
}
```

Category service looks like this:

```
getCategories(): Promise<Category[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.appConfig.apiEndpoint + 'categories/').toPromise()
  .then(response => response.json().map(obj => new Category(obj)))
  .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Api response:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"cat1"},{"id":2,"name":"cat2"}]
```

Template:

```
<select multiple name="category" [(ngModel)]="obj.post.category">
    <option  *ngFor="let category of categories" [ngValue] = "category">
       {{category.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Comment: In your code `Post` is declared as an interface, it should be a class. Also is `Category` an interface or a class ? If it is an interface and `obj.category` has the same shape as the expected interface your code should work fine

Comment: Category is `export class`

Comment: `obj.category` is an object with what runtime shape ? You should provide more information. What is an example of `obj`, what does the `Category` class look like ?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I added more details in my code. `obj.category` has the same structure as Category api repsonse. Could it works without changing `export class Category` into interface?

Comment: And what error are you getting, the code looks ok, you take the response array and you use `map` to convert it to an array of `Category`

Comment: In above code the main problem is that `post.category` is not `Category[]` type and options are not initially selected in dropdown (I added part of template to code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160917/discussion-between-pelcomppl-and-titian-cernicova-dragomir).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Possible answer

```
export interface Category {
 name: string;
 prop: string;
}
export class Post {
    category: Category[];
    constructor(obj: any) {
        this.category = obj.category as Category[];
    }
}
`
```

Comment: I tried this solution but my app doesn't work with Category  as interface.

Comment: You can see in service above: `obj => new Category(obj)` and it not works with interface.