# Angular : HttpClient Service and Observable custom type

Tags: angular, typescript, httpclient

My `getHeroes` function is supposed to return `Hero[]` Objects, but I cannot access its methods.
Am I doing something wrong ?

hero.ts

```
export class Hero {
  id: number;
  name: string;

  getName(): string {
    return this.name;
  }
}
```

heroes.service.ts

```
getHeroes (): Observable<Hero[]> {
    return this.http.get<Hero[]>(this.heroesUrl)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError('getHeroes', []))
      );
  }
```

heroes.component.ts

```
getHeroes(): void {
  this.heroesService.getHeroes()
    .subscribe(heroes => {
      this.heroes = heroes;
      this.heroes.forEach((hero) => console.log(hero));
      this.heroes.forEach((hero) => console.log(hero.getName())); //ERROR here
    });
}
```

I'm getting a `ERROR TypeError: hero.getName is not a function` on the last line.

Here is a live version [Live link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gzf6jl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fheroes%2Fheroes.component.ts)

Comment: Hero should be a interface instead of class..

Comment: Check the following link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47748170/how-to-cast-object-in-object-into-angular-class-type

Comment: @JeevaJsb why ? I still have an error event when hero is an interface.

Comment: Interface cannot be instantiate. For good practice use interface instead of class. For instantiate, please refer @ritaj's answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Http call returns an object (actually just a JSON string which will later by parsed by HttpClient) with id and name and no function. You can check that in your network tab.

What you could do is just use a contructor:

```
export class Hero {
  id: number;
  name: string;

  getName(): string {
    return this.name;
  }

  contructor(id, name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
   }
}
```

And later map the response from http call to the object you need:

```
getHeroes (): Observable<Hero[]> {
    return this.http.get<Hero[]>(this.heroesUrl)
      .pipe(
        map(hero => new Hero(hero.id, hero.name),
        catchError(this.handleError('getHeroes', []))
      );
  }
```

Comment: This would be the answer. Since we need to instantiate the class if the properties should be accessible.